# Mac OS X desktop background gets reset to "Andromeda Galaxy.jpg" when users log out

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, mcx

I'm running Mac OS 10.6 server, and have a set of 10.6 and 10.7 workstations connected to it for authentication and MCX.  Users have network profiles (home folder stored on server, via AFP).

When users are logged in, they can change their desktop background.  So far so good.

However, the *next* time they log in, their desktop background has been reset to "Andromeda Galaxy.jpg".

Though MCX is enabled and used to control other settings, MCX is disabled for the Desktop.

**What is keeping the users' desktop background from being preserved?  How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at **com.apple.desktop.plist** file located in */AFP_HomeFolder/Users/username/Library/Preferences/* (usually in local *~/Library/Preferences/*).

*To have the Library appearing in Lion, hold 'alt'(option) from the finder **Go** menu and select **Library**, or use **Go to folder** and type the path*

In this xml is defined the current desktop wallpaper used (Tag **ImageFilePath**).
Check the file permissions(POSIX/ACEs) and 'modified' timestamp metadata to figure if a user can write on this file.

Indeed, MCX might as well restrict write permission on this file.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks.  Unix permissions were fine.  Your answer prompted me to explore MCX some more, and I found an MCX setting lurking in somewhere I don't normally apply MCX — one of the groups this user belongs to.  After deleting that user group MCX, the wallpaper no longer resets.